# I don't receive data from formdata in my sails.js server

Tags: ajax, sails.js, multipartform-data, form-data

I have this ajax request:

```
this.sendApiRequestWithFile = function (method) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", "my name");

    data_ajax = {
        url: "http://localhost:1337/" + method,
        method: "PUT",
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----',
        }
    }

    return $http(data_ajax).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return data;
    });
}
```

And my server is in sails.js so I catch parameters like this: req.body and it doesn't work. I try req.params.all() and doesn't work too.

Comment: It is solved. The problem was that I had to use jquery to do an ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following code should work. If you try to access the uploaded file from server, use req.file("file_name")
       var fd = new FormData()
       fd.append("name", "name value")

```
    $.ajax({
       url: "/url",
       type: "POST",
       data: fd,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(response) {
           console.log("Success : " + response);
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
           console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
       }
    });
    });
```